# As3 some troubles with math and random selected objects [Help Please!]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math

I have some trouble getting things done in AS3. I have a var by the name of Rand and if this rand gets between the numbers 0 - 10 It will show the deathdisk. If rand gets between 90 - 100 the kingdisk will appear. The thing I want to achieve, Is that those Disks never show up two times in a row. I tried with Boolean but it didn’t work. Besides that The king and death disk must only appear if "var" rand is between the numbers i mentioned. Sometimes it appears outside the rand numbers. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

**Some info:**

disks is a MC and a button. This MC disks haves 8 frames in it 1 - 6 are normal disks and 7 & 8 the king and death disks. You can compare disks with a dice. When the player presses the disks Movieclip a random frame will be selected.

**diskRoll [class]:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.media.*;

    public class DiskRoll extends MovieClip 
    {
        //Vars

        var diskTilt:Timer = new Timer(1350,1);
        //var rand:int = Math.random() * 100;
        var rand:int = (Math.random()*(100));



        var deathDisk:Boolean = false;
        var kinghDisk:Boolean = false;

        //Sound Vars

        var diskFxChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
        var diskHitFx:Sound = new diskHitsound();   
        var diskRollFx:Sound = new diskRollSound(); 

        public function DiskRoll():void 
        {           
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hitDisk);
            diskTilt.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, tiltOnComplete);
            diskFxChannel = diskRollFx.play();
        }

        //Disk hit function

        private function hitDisk(event:MouseEvent):void{

            //Picks random frame after MOUSE_DOWN from Disks Mc [1-8 Frames total]
            this.gotoAndStop(Math.ceil(Math.random()* 6));

            //Genarate random number calc chances and luck
            rand = (Math.random() * (100));

            //Disk of death between Random number (block second time)
            if(rand >= 90 && rand <=100){ 
                this.gotoAndStop(7);
                kinghDisk = true;
            }

            if(rand >= 0 && rand <=10){ 
                this.gotoAndStop(8);
                deathDisk = true;
            }

            //Disk of death between Random number (block second time)
            if(deathDisk == true){
                rand = (Math.random() * (100))+11;
            }

            if(deathDisk == false){
                rand = (Math.random() * (100));
            }

            //KingsDisk Random between number (block second time)           
            if(kinghDisk == true){
                rand = (Math.random() * (89));
            }

            if(kinghDisk == false){
                rand = (Math.random() * (100));
            }                   

            //If statements per Disk
            if(this.currentFrame == 1){
                trace("DiskRoll 1")
                deathDisk = false;
                kinghDisk = false;
            }
            if(this.currentFrame == 2){
                trace("DiskRoll 2")
                deathDisk = false;
                kinghDisk = false;              
            }
            if(this.currentFrame == 3){
                trace("DiskRoll 3")
                deathDisk = false;
                kinghDisk = false;              
            }
            if(this.currentFrame == 4 /*&& stage.getChildByName("block") == null*/){
                trace("DiskRoll 4")
                deathDisk = false;
                kinghDisk = false;              
            }
            if(this.currentFrame == 5){
                trace("DiskRoll 5")
                deathDisk = false;
                kinghDisk = false;              
            }
            if(this.currentFrame == 6){
                trace("DiskRoll 6")
                deathDisk = false;
                kinghDisk = false;              
            }
            if(this.currentFrame == 7){
                trace("DiskRoll 7")
                deathDisk = false;
                kinghDisk = true;               
            }
            if(this.currentFrame == 8){
                trace("DiskRoll 8")
                deathDisk = true;
                kinghDisk = false;              
            }

            trace(rand);
            trace(deathDisk);
            trace(kinghDisk);

            diskFxChannel = diskHitFx.play();

            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hitDisk);

            diskTilt.start();

        }

        //Deblock Disk (button) Timer
        private function tiltOnComplete(event:TimerEvent):void {

            this.gotoAndPlay(1);
            diskTilt.stop();
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hitDisk);

            diskFxChannel = diskRollFx.play();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO. If I'll try to explain with A and B to be more clear.
You want A to appear 10% of cases.
You want B to appear 80% of cases.
You want C to appear 10% of cases.
You want to never get an AA or CC or AC.

Now, make an array with the elements A and C which is 20% of your final array. Shuffle it by applying a sort function which its condition is Math.random() < 0.5.

Now, insert 1 element B between every 2 elements. You should have enough to go around from the 80% of the final array. This will ensure no two disks are consecutive.

Now insert the rest of the B's wherever you want, it won't matter. Do it randomly, of course. Just Math.random() * temporaryArray.length to get a random index in the array where to insert it.

If there are any questions or clarifications needed, shoot :)

**EDIT**

```
//used some string to identify them. you use your instances
        var deathDisk : String = "death";
        var kingDisk  : String = "king";
        var normalDisk : String = "normal";

        //Any nr of total disks. I reserve 10% of death and 10% of king. The rest are normal.
        var totalNrOfDisks : Number = 40;
        var nrOfDeath : uint = totalNrOfDisks * 10 / 100;
        var nrOfKing  : uint = totalNrOfDisks * 10 / 100;

        //Generate all kings and deaths.
        var kingAndDeath : Array = [];
        for( var i : int = 0; i < nrOfDeath; i++ ) 
        {
            kingAndDeath.push( deathDisk );
        }
        for( i  = 0; i < nrOfKing; i++ ) 
        {
            kingAndDeath.push( kingDisk );
        }

        //shuffle them
        kingAndDeath.sort( function( element0:Number, element1:Number ):Boolean
        {
            return Math.random() < 0.5;
        });

        //Put at least 1 normal between them.
        var allArray : Array = [];
        for( i  = 0; i < kingAndDeath.length; i++ ) 
        {
            allArray.push( normalDisk );
            allArray.push( kingAndDeath[ i ] );
        }


        //While there is room for normals (max nr of disks not attained), insert one at a random spot in the array.
        while( allArray.length < totalNrOfDisks )
        {
            var randomIndex : uint = Math.random() * allArray.length;

            allArray.splice( randomIndex, 0, normalDisk );
        }
        trace( allArray );
```

Comment: Some clarification would be nice. Can you write a example. Thanks

Comment: @user1492440 there you go mate :D would appreciate feedback / vote / answer

Comment: Your the best around nothing's ever gonna keep you down!!! :D, Thank you so much you must feel good about your self. You helped some one out today!!! Thanks a lot!!!